# How do I display a quote for 24 hours

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display a quote on my site for daily basis. after 24 hours it should change. quotes are stored in MySQL database. how do I do this with PHP

Thanks

Mathew

Comment: Do they get deleted after 24 hours? or can they be reused?

Comment: yes it is in a separate table

Comment: that doesn't answer either of @Russell's questions :D

Comment: sorry It will get deleted and inserted with new one. they should not reused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something along the lines of using the following:

```
quotes
------
quote_id
..
.

quote_rota
----------
quote_rota_id
quote_id
date_shown
```

Then use a query such as the following to get a random quote that is not one of the past 7 quotes that have been displayed:

```
SELECT * FROM quotes WHERE id=(
  SELECT FLOOR(MIN(quote_id)+(RAND()*MAX(quote_id)) 
  FROM quotes
) AND quote_id NOT IN (
  SELECT quote_id FROM quote_rota ORDER BY date_shown DESC LIMIT 7
) LIMIT 1;

// process and retrieve quote_id then store in quote_rota
```

If you store the result in a file that is populated by a CRON job/ scheduled task, then you could have this lasting as long as you wish (e.g. 24 hours, 7 days, 1 hour, etc)

Alternatively, you could add a column to the quote table to indicate that it is the "current" quote (e.g. active) and then use:

```
SELECT quote_id FROM quotes WHERE id=(
  SELECT FLOOR(MIN(quote_id)+(RAND()*MAX(quote_id)) 
  FROM quotes
) AND quote_id NOT IN (
  SELECT quote_id FROM quote_rota ORDER BY date_shown DESC LIMIT 7
) LIMIT 1;

// process and retrieve quote_id then update "current" flag
```

Schedule this task as often as required and then use something like the following to get the quote:

```
SELECT * FROM quotes WHERE active = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be to store the day a quote is supposed to be shown on the site as a column in the mySQL table, and then make a query for that specific quote like

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM quotes WHERE date = CURDATE();";
```

if you don't store the date in your database, it becomes more difficult and complex - you'd have to display random entries but keep track of which one was shown when so the same quote doesn't come up twice in short succession. All doable, but possibly more complex than necessary.

Comment: Maybe it would be possible to use some kind of hashing mechanism to determine the quote to be displayed? Just work out some way of mapping a date to a unique quote record.

Comment: @Will nice idea! One could define a starting point (e.g. today = row 1) and count the days from that point. Day 30 will be row 30, day 31 row 31.... and so on.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a set of quotes, you may use modulus to ensure the difference between current date and a reference date will fall into the range of number of quotes in your db table.

```
SELECT *
FROM `quotes`
WHERE id = DATEDIFF( CURDATE( ) , '2010-05-01' ) MOD (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `quotes`)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a cron tab with your server that runs every 24 hour. However, setting it up depends on what server you have. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron for more information about cron. IF you're using cPanel, www.upstartblogger.com/how-to-create-a-cron-job-in-cpanel might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Many ways.

One way could be to have 2 more columns in your quotes table 'isdisplayed' and 'displayedwhen'.

Using these 2 extra fields you can keep track of which quote is displayed and for how long it has been displayed for.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any cache solution and you don't want to attach date of future use for each quote, you can do something like:

```
SELECT id, quote FROM quotes WHERE date_used = NOW();
```

if this returns null, do something like:

```
$count = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM quotes WHERE date_used = '0000-00-00'
```

to fetch number of unused quotes, then select one quote randomly:

```
$rand = rand (0, $count);
$quote = SELECT id, quote FROM quotes WHERE date_used = '0000-00-00' LIMIT $rand, 1
UPDATE quotes SET date_used = NOW() WHERE id = $quote['id']
```

Comment: My question is suppose I do have two table one is filled with quotes and other is empty. when I call command to show quots then it should insert to the second one with current date and time. every time page loads it should check time against stored one.when the time is over data in second table must get update with another one with new date and time. what you think??